# Assume IAM role from Cognito group

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Is it possible to assume the IAM role `iam-role1` linked to Cognito group `cognito-group1` of cognito user `cognito-user1` in Cognito User Pool `cognito-user-pool1`?

My configuration:

Cognito User pool `cognito-user-pool1`:

- Cognito user `cognito-user1` belongs to `cognito-group1`
- Cognito group `cognito-group1` has assigned to `iam-role1` .

Cognito Identity pool `cognito-identity-pool1`:

- Authentication providers: `cognito-user-pool1`
- authenticated role = `iam-role1`

IAM:

- IAM role `iam-role1` has policy to access S3 ReadOnly

This code allows me to authenticate to Cognito User Pool:

```
AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient();
            CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool("user-pool-id", "client-id", provider);
            CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser("cognito-user1", "client-id", userPool, provider);
            InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
            {
                Password = "cognito-password1"
            };

            AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest);
```

Then get the credentials from cognito identity pool `cognito-identity-pool1` linked to cognito user pool `cognito-user-pool1`:

```
CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials("identity-pool-arn", RegionEndpoint.USEast1); 
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials))
...
```

Answer (score 5):

When a user is authenticated with Cognito User Pool `cognito-user-pool1`, the id token includes cognito groups and iam roles:

```
"cognito:groups": [
    "cognito-group1"
  ],
"cognito:roles": [
    "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/iam-role1"
  ],
```

We need configure Cognito Identity Pool to choose role from token when user is authenticated:
[image]

We also need to allow Cognito Identity Pool to assume this role by editing trust relationship in IAM role `iam-role1`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    ...
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my life! I could not find any doc or clear example about attaching the Cognito group role to Cognito users who have signed in.