# Not able to give a Cognito User access on a certain S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a user pool and an Identity pool, where the role i am giving the authenticating users in the identity pool has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:CreateBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket123",
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket456",
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket987"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a new role called `Role_testbucket456_User_X` using Web Identity and added a condition where `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub` is stringEquals to `8e23d688-1f28-445c-8966-fdcb967c8e3c`, and attach to it the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket456"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I have added the Cognito user Y that has the sub `8e23d688-1f28-445c-8966-fdcb967c8e3c` to a Cognito User Pool Group called `testbucket456_Users`

And then attached the role `Role_testbucket456_User_X` to this group `testbucket456_Users`

What I am expecting is that none of the Cognito users will have Read/Write access on any S3 bucket, except the user Y that has sub `8e23d688-1f28-445c-8966-fdcb967c8e3c` to be able to access Read/Write on `testbucket456` bucket. But that didn't work unfortunately.

So I have added the following Bucket Policy to the `testbucket456` bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCognitoUserAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::5555555555555:role/Role_testbucket456_User_X"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket456/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCognitoUserAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::5555555555555:role/Role_testbucket456_User_X"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket456"
        }
    ]
}
```

But that still didn't work, I am still getting Access Denied issue whenever I try to call this method:

```
const listObjectParams = {
  Bucket: 'testbucket456',
};
s3.listObjects(listObjectParams, (err: any, data: any) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(data);
  console.log(`Successfully listed objects in `);
});
```

---

#### Note

When I set the `testbucket456` bucket's policy to

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCognitoUserAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket456/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCognitoUserAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket456"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am then able to access(list objects) the bucket using the Cognito users, I think the issue is with the bucket's policy itself and in the `Principal` field specifically.

---

**Possible issues**

- Maybe the authenticated role must have permissions to assume the custom role

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::5555555555555:role/Role_testbucket456_User_X"
}
```

to be like the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket456"
            ]
        },
        {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::5555555555555:role/Role_testbucket456_User_X"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anybody confirm please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62970593/14335507) was the solution, I had to change the default role given to the Cognito Users